# call php script from python (subprocess)

Tags: php, python, process, subprocess

I have a php script that I called in command line like that :

```
$php importTextFile.php --user "X" --title "name" notice_X.txt
```

I want to use that file in a python script. I've tried :

```
for file in os.listdir("."):
    subprocess.call(["php", "-f", "importTextFile.php"], "--user=X", "--title="'%s' % name, file)
```

I've got he following error :

```
  File "./pageFromFile.py", line 21, in main
    subprocess.call(["php", "-f","importTextFile.php"], "--user=Bot", "--title="'%s' % nom, fichier)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 629, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

I don't understand how to fix this error.
Thanks for your help.

**edit1** : thanks it works, but I've got problem withs args because the Usage message appeared :

```
Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
       php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] -- [args...]
       php [options] -a
```

edit2 : I've changed arguments's order and it works :
["php", "php /script /path", "-f", "--user", "X", "--title", X, file ]

Comment: Any reason why you cannot do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a messy explanation due to messy documentation.

From: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

> To support a wide variety of use cases, the Popen constructor (and the
>   convenience functions) accept a large number of optional arguments.
>   For most typical use cases, many of these arguments can be safely left
>   at their default values. The arguments that are most commonly needed
>   are:

From: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

The signature for call() is:

```
subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)
```

You'll want your CL arguments all within a single list - as Jakob provided.  That is the first argument to call().

The other positional arguments correspond to initialization parameters for class subprocess.Popen (http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).  bufsize happens to be one of them.

Answer (score 5):

```
subprocess.call(["php", "-f", "importTextFile.php", "--user=X", "--title="'%s' % name, file])
```

Should fix it