# Can't rm -r directory using python subprocess.call

Tags: python, shell, exception, subprocess, rm

Welp, I need to remove some huge temporary directories from python and I can't seem to use rm -r. I'm working thought a big dataset (on s3) I don't have the disc space to leave them around.

The usual way I would call a command from python is

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('rm','-r','/home/nathan/emptytest')
```

That gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 629, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

What's this all about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [call php script from python (subprocess)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780958/call-php-script-from-python-subprocess)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're calling it the wrong way.  The first argument should be a list:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['rm','-r','/home/nathan/emptytest'])
```

You might also just want to try and use [shutitl.rmtree](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree)

Comment: yeah i think shutil.rmtree is what I really want.

Comment: I tried this in a try-except block and it fails. What would be the reason for it? It did work as you said.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation,

```
  >> In [3]: subprocess.call?
  Type:           function
  Base Class:     <type 'function'>
  String Form:    <function call at 0x01AE79F0>
  Namespace:      Interactive
  File:           c:\python26\lib\subprocess.py
  Definition:     subprocess.call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  Docstring:
      Run command with arguments.  Wait for command to complete, then
  return the returncode attribute.
  The arguments are the same as for the Popen constructor.  Example:
  retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
```

So try:

```
subprocess.call(['rm','-r','/home/nathan/emptytest'])
```